# ¿Como mostrar todos los nombres de los alumnos que tengan nota mayor a 7?

Tags: java

Estoy haciendo un programa donde debo ingresar nombres y notas de alumnos, cuando se ingresa como nota -1 termina el programa.
También me pide imprimir los nombres de los alumnos con nota mayor a 7.
Todo funciona bien , pero cada vez que ingreso una nota mayor a 7 a continuación me imprime el nombre , lo que yo quiero es que los nombres con notas mayor lo imprima a lo último.

Intente poner un `for` y no pasa nada , solo me imprime el ultimo nombre que ingrese con nota mayor a 7.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class NotasYNombres{
    public static void main(String [] args){

        int nota = 0;
        int n = 0;
        String nombres = " ";
        String frase = " ";

        Scanner teclado = new Scanner (System.in);

        while(nota!=-1){

            n++;
            System.out.println("Ingrese nombre : ");
            nombres = teclado.next();
            System.out.println("Ingrese nota : ");
            nota=teclado.nextInt(); 

            for(int i = 0 ; i<=n ; i++){

                if(nota>7){

                    frase = "Nombres : "+nombres;
                }
            }
        }

         System.out.println(frase);

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hola por lo que veo eres principiante en java te explico. En cualquier lenguaje de programación si es que quieres mostrar valores al final de la ejecución de un programa tienes que guardarlos dentro de arreglos, en tu caso usas variables comunes y esto provoca que cada vez que finalizas el programa lo único que se haya guardado es el ultimo valor asignado, en este caso no podrás terminar tu programa indicando un -1 porque esto provocaría que tengas espacios vacíos en el arreglos por lo que es mejor limitar tu arreglo a cierta cantidad de valores.

NOTA: En el caso de que quieras finalizar tu programa con -1 deberás de usar algo llamado arreglos dinámicos.

```
int nota[] = new int[3];
String nombres[] = new String[3];
Scanner teclado = new Scanner(System.in);

    for (int i = 0; i < nombres.length; i++) {
        System.out.println("Ingrese nombre : ");
        nombres[i] = teclado.next();
        System.out.println("Ingrese nota : ");
        nota[i] = teclado.nextInt();
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < nota.length; i++) {
        if (nota[i] >= 7) {
            System.out.println("--------APROBADOS--------");
            System.out.println("Alumno: " + nombres[i] + " Nota: " + nota[i]);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Estaba intentando usar arrays pero con un solo for , y no me daba , ahora si , muchas gracias x tu tiempo :)

Answer (score 0):

Que quiere decir

```
String nombres = " ";
```

Que declarasta una variable nombres que es de tipo string.

Y eso que quiere decir? que esa variable, solo puede tener un valor.

ni dos, ni tres, ni cuatro. Solo uno.

Entonces si vos queres guardar muchos numeros, tenes que usar algun tipo de estructura donde se puedan guardar muchos datos. Aca es donde tu profesor o donde estes estudiando tienen que ayudarte. Esto lo podes guardar en una lista, un array o donde sea.

Pero no en una variable de tipo string. Que solo guarda una cadena. Y cuando se le pasa otra, reemplaza la anterior